# How to Reorder Language Parameter In URL using URL Rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

We have a **Ruby On Rails** application on *parent folder* and a **Wordpress Multisite** hosted in a *subfolder* named **Blog**. Hosting is provided by **Azure** and we are using **IIS**.

On the **Ruby On Rails** app an example url is below:

```
http://sitename.azurewebsites.net/{language-parameter}/card.html
```

Note that language parameter **e.g. tr** comes first.

**Wordpress Multisite** contains sites with each site has it's own url with language parameter only.

For example the Turkish site's homepage url is

```
https://wxtemp.azurewebsites.net/blog/tr/
```

and a sample post url is

```
http://sitename.azurewebsites.net/blog/tr/{post-slug}/
```

Notice that language parameter **tr** comes after /blog/ directory. Although we host Ruby on Rails app on / parent folder, can we customize its web.config file and add some kind of **URL rewrite rule** to handle changes, so browser address bar displays Wordpress links as

```
http://sitename.azurewebsites.net/tr/blog/{post-slug}/
```

and *redirects visitors to this url* if they are coming from:

```
http://sitename.azurewebsites.net/blog/tr/{post-slug}/
```

We want to have same approach for urls with language parameters of other languages we use as well. Parameters we use are de, es, fr, it, ms, ar etc... So I think what we need is a rule with a regex pattern.

Comment: You can try excellent plugin [Multisite Language Switcher](https://bs.wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/) that can be configured to put the language parameter after the domain but before any other parameter.

Comment: @Danijel Thanks, I'm already using that excellent plugin and it does great job switching between sites. Could you please tell me which section to use for that change? In my example each language has it's own site on WP Multisite environment.

Comment: It's been awhile since I done it, but if I remember correctly the `/blog/` part shoud be removed from the permalink structure in network admin settings tab for each site, and also should change the base page url ( if is not changed by plugin ). Maybe this [link](http://www.jennybeaumont.com/remove-blog-slug-multisite-installations/) can be more helpful.

Comment: @Danijel, unfortunately, your suggestion applies to second slug added by wordpress linking system. What I'm looking for is to remove the one placed on url, due to blog is being virtual directory name that hosts the application.